# How to ensure the bluetooth is switched off after boot up?

Tags: gnome, debian, bluetooth

Please show me which magic button to press for the case where I'm tired of manually switching off the distracting bluetooth light on my laptop after every boot-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: I am unable to test this answer.*

Assuming that you want to shut off bluetooth and not just the indicator light, the [rfkill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/rfkill.8.html) utility does what you want. The following command should disable bluetooth:

```
$ rfkill block bluetooth
```

In order to do this on every boot, this line can be placed in `/etc/rc.local`, another custom init script, or (if available) an upstart script.  I recommend using the full path of the executable inside `/etc/rc.local` or in an custom init script.  On my system this is `/sbin/rfkill`, but can be found using the command `which rfkill`.  Thus on my system, I would place the following command within `/etc/rc.local` somewhere before `exit 0`:

```
 /sbin/rfkill block bluetooth
```

Depending on your Debian setup, you may not have `/etc/rc.local`.  In this case, a custom init script may be the way to go.  The init script could be saved at `/etc/init.d/disable-bluetooth` and contain something like:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 /sbin/rfkill block bluetooth
```

Then ensure the command is executable (`chmod 755`) and add it to startup (`update-rc.d disable-bluetooth defaults`).

An example of an upstart upstart script would be a file named `/etc/init/disable-bluetooth.conf` containing something like:

```
description "Disable Bluetooth devices"

start on startup

task
exec /sbin/rfkill block bluetooth
```

`rfkill` uses `/dev/rfkill` which is an [interface provided by the Linux kernel](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/rfkill.txt).

Comment: Debian hasn't adopted Upstart.

Comment: I was under the impression they were moving to upstart.  I removed the reference to debian, but kept the upstart script since someone might find it useful anyway.

Comment: I updated it with examples using plain old init scripts.

Answer (score 0):

On debian/kali please check following:

in */etc/default/bluetooth* `BLUETOOTH_ENABLED=0`

in */etc/bluetooth/main.conf* `AutoEnable=false`

and if you have *blueman-applet*, check it's plugin PowerManager settings